# How do I resume a dictionary attack using a custom starting number?

Tags: dictionary

The script below generates 8 digit strings using a combination of characters `0123456789` from number 00000000 to 99999999.

```
crunch 8 8 0123456789 | aircrack-ng -a 2 'HOME-TC-FILE-CAP' -e 'ESSID' -b 'HANDSHAKE' -w -
```

I haven't finished generating all of the password.

How do I resume the dictionary attack using custom starting number, for example from 02000000 to 99999999?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `-s` argument to specify starting point, per [Crunch wiki](https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Crunch):

> `-s <startblock>`
>
> Optional. Allows you to specify the starting string, eg: 03god22fs